# @connect tag not working in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tampermonkey

I have a small problem, I have a script (I'm using Tampermonkey) and when I make a POST request, it says:

> VM2584:33 Refused to connect to "https://my_url.com/sub1/sub2/": URL is not a part of the @connect list

The thing that it IS the part of that "@connect list"

```
// @name         My Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        url.com/*
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/master/src/js.cookie.js
// @connect      https://my_url.com/sub1/sub2/
```

So where's the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Refer to [the documentation for the `@connect` directive](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_connect).  It **takes a domain**, not a URL.

So your `@connect` statement(s) would be like:

```
// @connect my_url.com
```

Comment: To add to this, trailing "/" will also break this: e.g. "my_url.com/" must be changed to "my_url.com"